# How to derive equation from total derivative to partial derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

[image]

Above picture, I want to know this derivation that

$$
\frac{d}{dT}*∫^T_tf(t,u)du = ∫^T_t\frac{∂}{∂T}f(t,u)du + f(t,T)\frac{d}{dT}*T - 0
$$

I think $\frac{d}{dT}$ means total derivative. So to come up with $\frac{∂}{∂T}$ : partial derivative notation, I think, it should also come up with $\frac{∂}{∂t}$! But As you can see it doesn't deal with that term.

What makes me even uncomfortable is that this part : $∫^T_t\frac{∂}{∂T}f(t,u)du + f(t,T)\frac{d}{dT}*T$

$\frac{∂}{∂T}, \frac{d}{dT}$ are alive together! From the only one equation!
I mean, it should be something like this below,

$$
\frac{d}{dT}*∫^T_tf(t,u)du
 = \frac{∂}{∂T} \left(∫^T_tf(t,u)du\right)dT
 + \frac{∂}{∂t} \left(∫^T_tf(t,u)du\right)dt
$$

Additionaly, how the partial derivative get in the integral notation?
I mean, $∫^T_t\frac{∂}{∂T}f(t,u)du$. not $\frac{∂}{∂T}∫^T_tf(t,u)du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $t$ and $u$ are independent of $T$, this result follows directly from the [fundamental theorem of calculus, part 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part)
$$
{\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_a^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t = f(x).
$$

What may be causing your confusion is the correct, but completely unnecessary use of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)
$$
{\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t = f(x,b(x)){\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}b(x) - f(x,a(x)){\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{d}x}a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\partial \over \partial x}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t
$$
since in your case $f$ is not a function of $T$.